# Is SInt32 AudioUnitSampleType actually holding the whole audio data?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, core-audio

The SInt32 confuses me, as I would think that audio data samples are represented in an array. So how can SInt32 AudioUnitSampleType store the audio data? Or is this basically an array of many SInt32 values?

Comment: Yes, the sample type is an array of samples. It's an 8.24 fixed point format. More info can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole audio stream is stored as an array of samples, yes. But there are different ways to actually store those samples in memory - signed integer, unsigned integer, floating point and so on. And that is exactly what the `AudioUnitSampleType` constants tell you - which format a single sample is stored in. The `SInt32AudioUnitSampleType` uses a signed (`S`) integer (`Int`) that is 32 bits wide (`32`) to store a single sample. It doesn’t tell you anything else about that audio stream though.

Comment: [Details of the format are here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323739/how-to-manually-convert-8-24-bit-deinterleaved-lpcm-to-16-bit-lpcm)